# R - How can I strip a nested vector to obtain a list of tokens?

Tags: r, list, vector, nested, token

Hello stackoverflow community, I encounter the following issue:

I created a table column with the attribute `<list>`. Every row (cell) inside the column contains a different group of words included in a vector, e.g. 

ROW 1: c("table", "wall", "clock", ...)

ROW 2: c("say", "game", "from", ...)
etc.

Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to retrieve tokens from these nested vectors. To solve this issue, I would like to have a simple tokens list in each row, e.g.
ROW 1: table, wall, clock, ...

ROW 2: say, game, from, ...
etc.

Is such a conversion possible?

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: British English

Comment: ctenar meant which programming language, like python... or sql, and if do for which db system

Comment: R 3.6.1. At the beginning I had tokenized the text and I obtained clean lists of tokens in all table cells. Then I replaced some tokens and I got these nested vectors. Now I cannot get rid of them.

Comment: I have found a solution: I removed the first character ("c") from all nested character vectors and then I used the function tokenize_words from the tokenizers package. Now I have a list of tokens.

Comment: This is the gsub function for removing the first character: df$text_col <- gsub("^.{0,1}", "", df$text_col)